# Plotting the histogram of 2 images which have different shapes

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, histogram

I want to plot on the same figure the histogram of different images which do not have the same shape.
First I thought to get the biggest shape and calculate the augmentation factor between the smaller shapes and the biggest to finally normalize by it.

But it gives me a lot of variations.

For example if a have a (100,100,1) image shape and a (25,25,1) image shape, the factor is 16 because the first one have 16 time more pixel than the second one. (4*4)

the code is

```
import scipy.ndimage as scim
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (12,8))

band = np.random.uniform(0,1, size = (100,100,1))
ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 1)    ## a voir comment modifier en fct du nb de canaux
x = np.linspace(band.min(), band.max(), 50)
y = scim.histogram(band, band.min(), band.max(), 50)
ax.plot(x, y)

band = np.random.uniform(0,1, size = (25,25,1))
ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 1)    ## a voir comment modifier en fct du nb de canaux
x = np.linspace(band.min(), band.max(), 50)
y = scim.histogram(band, band.min(), band.max(), 50)
ax.plot(x, y*16) #here i multiply by 16 to get the same size
plt.show()
```

The 2 histograms are too different.
How can I get something more realistic than this?

Answer (score 0):

An usual approach is to normalize the histograms, for example by their integral (you could also do it by their maximum value, depending on the shape of the histograms):

```
import scipy.ndimage as scim
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (12,8))

band = np.random.uniform(0,1, size = (100,100,1))
ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 1)    ## a voir comment modifier en fct du nb de canaux
x = np.linspace(band.min(), band.max(), 50)
y = scim.histogram(band, band.min(), band.max(), 50)
ax.plot(x, y/y.sum())

band = np.random.uniform(0,1, size = (25,25,1))
ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 1)  
x = np.linspace(band.min(), band.max(), 50)
y = scim.histogram(band, band.min(), band.max(), 50)
ax.plot(x, y/y.sum()) 
plt.show()
```

Variations are intrinsic to the random noise you generate, I don't see what you expect to obtain 'But it gives me a lot of variations.'.

[image]

Comment: Actually i have 2 images that represent the same thing, but one is a coefficient bigger than the other. I want to plot the histograms of the 2 images and compare them. But the one of the smallest image is very noisy compared to the second one, but these noises are not true.

Comment: Can you edit your post showing the actual raw histograms of the two images, or something that gives a similar problem to yours ? I don't see the link with the random noises you made